# Chart.js bar chart not showing up

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

this is my `BarChart.vue` file

```html
<template>
  <canvas :id="`myChart`"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  // props: ['id', 'labels'],
  mounted() {
    // const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart' + this.id).getContext('2d');
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart' ).getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 5,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    myChart;
  },
};
</script>
```

I am calling it as `<BarChart />` in the parent file after adding it to the components, the chart doesn't show up but it creates a space in the DOM.

I have tried both `vue-chart.js` and normal `chart.js`, facing the same issue.

Comment: You're not supposed to use a `querySelector` in a SPA context, use [`$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) rather. Also, you don't need ```:id="`myChart`"```, keep it static here. Otherwise, you will need to double-check your browser's console to see if there are any errors down there.

Comment: I also assumed that you're using Vue2, but that may not be the case. Anyway, please see if you're using the good version for your version of Vue here: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs#how-to-use